# How to make UIImageView correct frame size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, frame

I'm trying to take a picture using imagePickerController and show the image in a UIImageView in another ViewController.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    PAWWallPostCreateViewController *wallPostCreateViewController = [[PAWWallPostCreateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PAWWallPostCreateViewController" bundle:nil];

    wallPostCreateViewController.myImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    wallPostCreateViewController.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:wallPostCreateViewController.myImage];
    wallPostCreateViewController.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    NSLog(@"%@",wallPostCreateViewController.imageView); // Output below
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:wallPostCreateViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The output in NSLog for the imageView is:

```
<UIImageView: 0x18f695b0; frame = (0 0; 640 640); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x18f14240>>
```

The frame is much too big for my actual UIImageView which is set to (60 227; 200 200)

**I think this is the reason why I can't see UIImageView at all when I run my app. How do I fix this?**

EDIT:

In PAWWallPostCreateViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

I linked imageView to my .xib file

**Also is anyone familiar with autoresize = RM+BM; Because usually when I have used imagePickerController to put the UIImage in a UIImageView of the same view controller my UIImageView data has a autoresize = RM+BM; attribute
so the code I want usually looks like**

```
<UIImageView: 0x1a2b4b30; frame = (60 227; 200 200); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1a2b4bb0>>
```

**But that's now what I'm getting in this case**

Comment: try imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: doesn't do anything. I updated the code to show what I did

Comment: Can you show how you added imageview in PAWWallPostCreateViewController?

Comment: I edited the code above. I just defined the @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView; in my .h file And linked it to my .xib file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just call this line under your second view controller in ViewDidLoad()

```
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: have u given any fix frame for imageivew?

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment. This actually fixed the problem! Now in NSLog I receive the correct size but I still don't see the UIImage or UIImageView when I run my app. there must be another issue somewhere... So I'll have to do a bit of searching